# Code Standard Plugin for NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

As the title states, i need a plugin to maintain code standard in my project.

At school we are learning java(never really used it), and we have to work in a team. The project we are creating is on Github so we can all work on it.

When i was using c#(visual studio) we had a plugin called: "ReSharper" and with that plugin you can set a code standard(and lot's more), and the settings will be shared to Github as well, so everyone with ReSharper installed had the same settings.

My question: Is there something equivalent to ReSharper in Java(Netbeans)?

PS. I know netbeans has a option to import/export code standards and edit them but i'm more interested in a way that it will share to everyone using the same plugin.

Thanks in advance.